# How to simulate mouse with a Leap Motion in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

Now I'm creating a windows application using Unity and Leap Motion. So I wanna know how to simulate my hand to become a mouse that can do any Events that I want (Ex. Grabbing = Left Click).

Is there any way to do it ? or do I need some third person application (or plugin) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Leap Motion's Unity Modules Package?